# Arduino bitRead() outputing binary number using LED

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, arduino-uno

I am now trying to have my Arduino Uno to output a binary number sent from my mobile phone through bluetooth. The mobile phone would be sending an integer to the Arduino. Hopefully the Arduino converts the integer into binary and turning on corresponding LED. 4 LEDs are used to represent the binary number. However, the LED just flashes once or all the LED turn on when I input a number. Here is my code:

```
int li1;
const byte numPins = 4;
int pins[] = {10,11,12,13};

void setup () {
    Serial.begin(19200);
    pinMode(10,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(11,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(12,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  while(!Serial.available());
  li1 = Serial.read(); 
  for (byte i=0; i<numPins; i++) {
     byte temp = bitRead(li1, i);
    digitalWrite(pins[i],temp);
    }
  }
```

li1 is the variable I get from the mobile phone. 
Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the answer, but do not have enough reputation to leave a comment.

Try setting a sleep after you write the bytes in case its going away to quick.

```
    int li1;
const byte numPins = 4;
int pins[] = {10,11,12,13};

void setup () {
    Serial.begin(19200);
    pinMode(10,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(11,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(12,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  while(!Serial.available());
  li1 = Serial.read(); 
  for (byte i=0; i<numPins; i++) {
     byte temp = bitRead(li1, i);
    digitalWrite(pins[i],temp);
    delay(4000); 
    }
  }
```